# class method triggered without being called

Tags: javascript, ios, html5-audio

I've defined a class to handle playing audio files. I'm instantiating the class, and calling its `addEventListener()` method at which time, `playSound()` is being triggered without the element being tapped. Also, when I call `getEventListeners(bgMusic.elem)` - the listener is no longer attached.

```
class WebAudio {

    constructor(soundFile, elem) {
        this.soundFile = soundFile;
        this.elem = elem;
        this.audio = new Audio('sound/' + this.soundFile);
    }

    addListener() {
        this.elem.addEventListener('touchstart', this.playSound());
    }

    playSound() {
        if (context.state != 'suspended') {
            console.log('playing audio file');
            if (!this.audio.playing) {
                this.audio.play();
            }
        } else {
            console.log("Audio Context locked? " + context.state)
        }
    }

}

var AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
var context = new AudioContext();
function webAudioTouchUnlock(context) {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        //if AudioContext is suspended, and window has been interacted with
        if (context.state === 'suspended' && 'ontouchstart' in window) {
           console.log(context.state);
           var unlock = () => {
               //resume AudioContext (allow playing sound), remove event listeners
               context.resume().then(() => {
                   console.log("context resumed");
                   document.body.removeEventListener('touchstart', unlock);
                   document.body.removeEventListener('touchend', unlock);
                   resolve(true);
               }, function (reason) {
                 reject(reason);
               });
           };
           document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', unlock, false);
           document.body.addEventListener('touchend', unlock, false);
       } else {
           console.log('context not suspended? Context is ' + context.state);
           resolve(false);
       }
    });
}

webAudioTouchUnlock(context);
let bgMusic = new WebAudio('bensound-clearday.mp3', document.querySelector('#sound_button'));
bgMusic.addListener();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add the event listener like:

```
 this.elem.addEventListener('touchstart', this.playSound());
```

You care calling the function: `this.playSound()` and adding the result of that function (`undefined`) as the listener.

You just want to add the reference to the function:

```
this.elem.addEventListener('touchstart', this.playSound);
```

so the listener can call it when it needs too.

Also you will probably need to use something like this to maintain the proper `this`:

```
this.elem.addEventListener('touchstart', () => this.playSound());
```

or:

```
this.elem.addEventListener('touchstart', this.playSound.bind(this));
```